# What is the fastest way to read a csv file

Tags: performance, memory, time-series, compression

I need to read a csv file into main memory and I would like to know the fastest programming language for doing that.
The file contains a time series:

time, value
1366810163,177.413
1366810164,177.303
1366810165,177.413
1366810166,178.9797

I want to evaluate the I/O Performance improvements on compressing the data as it is already done here:
http://entland.homelinux.com/blog/2006/10/25/reading-files-as-fas-as-possible/
This blog is from 2006 and only targeting C++ programming language.
But I also want to evaluate the I/O costs for Decompression.

So you could help me with your experience in any programming language / operating system.
Then I will sum up your answers and make a guide.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since the IO is the bottleneck of such application I think the room for performance optimization will be highly depended on the hardware you are using. How many hard disks have you got? Can you split the file onto a few partitions? What is your hard driver controller? Do you use RAID? What is the operating system and the filesystem type?

Comment: For first experiments it is evaluated on just one SSD drive. I am just asking for your experience on any OS with any Programming Language and Filesystem. (I hope this is not too unspecific, but I would use whatever is best)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C or C++ with [zlib](http://zlib.net/) will be the fastest, if written properly.  (Assembler could be faster still, though for large programs its getting harder to beat good compilers.)

[zlib's gz* functions](http://zlib.net/manual.html#Gzip) will read a file that is compressed with gzip or not transparently.  It is usually faster to read less data from the mass storage device and decompress, than it is to read more uncompressed data from the mass storage device.  Even with an SSD.

On my 2 GHz i7, I can read in and parse a 56.2 MiB CSV file with 201429 records of 24 fields each in about 0.3 seconds of CPU time if uncompressed, 0.4 seconds if compressed.  In real time after memory buffers have been purged, reading from an SSD, it's 0.5 seconds if compressed, 0.6 seconds if not compressed.  (Note the reversal between CPU time and real time.)

Comment: can you provide the code of the tool you have used in this experiment? I would like to bet that it is possible to write an equally fast tool in Java, but it just has to be tested on a larger file than 56MB. more like 500MB, as the Java JVM has to warm up.

Comment: I can't provide the code.  It's probably not as useful as you think if you're writing in Java.  My C code spends some effort minimizing malloc()'s for speed.  I doubt that you'll get a Java version working as fast, since there will be a lot more memory management going on.  My tip is to use RFC 4180 to make sure that you can read standard CSV files.

Comment: @MarkAdler: thank you for your answer, this was helpful. I already guessed that c/c++ would have some advantages compared to Java. So for the uncompressed way, what function do you use, fread()? Do you use the zlib's functions for reading the compressed data? Are there any code snippets, you could provide? Thank you again for your help!  With fread() I can read a 30 MB File with 1 561 660  records in about 0.3 seconds.

Comment: I used `gzread()` from zlib.  It works like `fread()` if the input is not compressed.

Comment: Would you help me out with the reading of the uncompressed file again? For now I use fgets() to read a line and then strtok() to split up the line and write it into an two-dimensional Array. My file has about 1561660 entries with a size of 30 MB. This lasts about 56 seconds on a Core i7, 2,3 MHz. How could I optimize that?

Comment: Simply use a character-by-character state machine to parse the lines.  Read large chunks of the file into memory at a time, then run the state machine on it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I can choose the hardware to optimize this task, raw data is kept as-is, no parsing required, and we have low level access to the hardware, then given these assumptions, XIP would be the fastest - time to load is zero!